# g++: Will -fno-omit-frame-pointer be effective if specified before -O2 or -O3?

Tags: c++, gcc, makefile, g++, compiler-flags

We have a complex hierarchical make file system where the `CXXFLAGS` is appended in several places (several separate makefiles of individual libraries).

There's one master file that seems to be getting included in every other make file. So I specified the `-fno-omit-frame-pointer` flag there.

When I compile, I see the above flag and after that I see `-O2`. My question is, if the `-O2` flag sets `-fomit-frame-pointer`, will the latest setting take effect?

Comment: Are you sure that `-fno-omit-frame-pointer` even matters for your architecture? For many common modern x86 architecturs it makes no real difference what-so-ever. In any case; just specify `-O2` or `-O3` and let the compiler worry about it.

Comment: Yes. It matters because I am trying to compile with this flag so I can use my profiler. My goal is that I want to compile with this flag enabled along with -O2 or -O3. I do not want -O2 or -O3 silently turning this off.

Comment: @Krishna - I now find myself in the exact same situation (possibly even the same project at the same company with the same proprietary profiling tool).  Were you ever able to determine what the behavior is in regards to the compiler argument ordering?

Answer (score 2):

With gcc/g++ you can use the `-Q --help=optimizers` flags to find out the exact set of optimizations that are enabled.

With my version of gcc I get:

```
$ gcc -Q --help=optimizers -O2 | fgrep omit-frame-pointer

-fomit-frame-pointer                [enabled]
```

and

```
$ gcc -Q --help=optimizers -fno-omit-frame-pointer -O2 | fgrep omit-frame-pointer

-fomit-frame-pointer                [disabled]
```

So `-O2` doesn't seem to overwrite the previous `-fno-omit-frame-pointer`.

Anyway check your environment.